# Closing Hole in mesh - Meshlab

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I am trying to close the bottom of a mesh using the "Close Hole" function under "Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction tab" but am having no luck. I have tried increasing the max size to be closed but the base of my mesh won't fill. Any ideas how I can overcome this?
Thanks!

[image: Mesh Hole]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your boundary is turned towards the exterior of the cylinder, so closing the hole building a patch of triangles would produce several undesired auto-collisions.

If you don't mind to move some vertex in the boundary, I would suggest using the filter sequence

```
Select Border
Laplacian Smooth
Close Holes (set a high number in the hole size parameter)
```

If this still don't solve your problem, I would discard the noisy faces in the boundary:

```
Select Border
Delete selected faces (supr key)
Select Border
Laplacian Smooth
Close Holes (set a high number in the hole size parameter)
```