# How to close hole at the bottom part of the model? Any specific way?

Tags: meshlab

How to close the bottom part of the model? I tried the close-hole filter but could not generate it. Is there any specific way or step to close the bottom part?

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739752/closing-hole-in-mesh-meshlab